# Find the largest side of the quadrilateral?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The second largest side of the quadrilateral is 10. Find the largest possible side of the quadrilateral?
Please tell how to solve it and what is the answer. I tried to use polygon inequality but it didnt helped much ?

Comment: What quadrilateral?

Comment: It is the largest possible side ?

Answer (score 2):

30.

Because the other two sides have to be less than 10 each, the largest couldn't be more than 30 as the sums of the other 3 needs to be longer than the longest side.